# Error when returning a pointer

Tags: c

I am practicing coding binary search tree in C and I ran into an error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*struct Node*/
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node* left;
    struct Node* right;
}Node;

/*Forward declaration*/
Node *createNode(int data);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Node *root;
    root = createNode(3); //ERROR

}

Node* createNode(int data){
    Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));

    if(newNode==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to allocate node\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right= NULL;
    return newNode;  //ERROR OCCURS HERE

}
```

I get a failed run when I try to run this. The error occurs during the return newNode. I am not sure why the point is not returning.

I am using netbeans and this is what it says

Comment: Not your bug, but it's not necessary to cast the result of `malloc`.

Comment: You need to give more information than 'the error occurs during the return newNode`. What is the error? Is it the error message you `fprintf` there, or something else? Is it really an error, or just an unexpected result? etc. Show us what happens when you run your code.

Comment: The code looks fine, so we do need to know what error you're seeing. One thing I noticed is that you don't have a `return` statement at the end of your `main` function, but I don't think that usually causes problems for most compilers.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Try adding `free(root);` before you return from `main()`.

Comment: @MattPatenaude: It's bad style, but it's actually ok not to `return` from `main()` (but *only* from `main()`, not for any other function).  If you don't return anything from `main()`, the compiler implicitly returns 0 for you.

Comment: That code compiles and runs fine. I therefore conclude that you've had a little too much to drink tonight :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Not sure why, but if you run that code on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com) you get an unspecified "runtime error", but if you add the call to `free()`, it goes away.

Comment: @MattPatenaude Not returning from `main` is only a problem in C89, but fine on C99/C11.

Comment: @Yu and Adam, That's what I thought, but perhaps if he's compiling with an old version of gcc that still defaults to C89?

Comment: @Paul, I would suggest then that ideaone is broken in some way. That's perfectly valid code.

Comment: @paxdiablo: I agree, hence the question to find out what compiler he's using.

Comment: You've updated with where the error occurs, but what we want more is what's the error message.

Comment: @YuHao: In C89, it's not Undefined Behavior to fail to return a value from `main`, it just returns an undefined value to the host environment.  C89 §2.1.2.2 says "If the main function executes a return that specifies no value, the termination status returned to the host environment is undefined."

Comment: @AdamRosenfield That certainly could explain a run-time problem, though, depending on the platform. It could be returning just gunk on the stack, which could be interpreted as a very strange error code.

Answer (score 4):

That code compiles and runs just fine in `gcc` in both c90 and c99 mode, so there's a couple of things you can do.

First and foremost, you should show us the *actual* error (that should have come with the original question).

Second, get a hex dump of the file to make sure there's no funny characters in it, such as with the command `od -xcb myprog.c`.

Thirdly, it's also good practice to return values from functions where you specify a non-void return type. Later iterations of C make this unnecessary for `main` but earlier iterations could result in random values being passed back to the environment. I still return zero from `main` even though I no longer have to (it's hard to break a thirty-year habit).

That last point may be what's happening here, depending on which compiler and version you're using. Without the explicit return from `main`, the compiler at ideaone gives a not very helpful message:

```
Runtime error time: 0 memory: 2376 signal:-1
```

When you put in the return, it starts working:

```
Success time: 0 memory: 2376 signal:0
```

Whether NetBeans has the same problem with its compiler I can't comment but it's worth checking out.

I *will* note that compiling this code with `gcc --std=c99` and then running it, gives a return code of 0 (with `echo $?`). However, compiling it with `gcc --std=c90` gives a return code of `8` when run. So that's the most likely cause, that NetBeans is interpreting the exit code after the program has finished.

> As an aside, you shouldn't cast the return value from `malloc` in C. It can hide some subtle errors if, for example, there's no prototype in scope for it and your integers and pointers are not compatible widths.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `#include<malloc.h>` , this helps in some of the compilers.